# Not Serializable Exception with Serializable Class in Java

Tags: java, serializable

I have a class named Vehicule in Java which implements the Serializable interface.
But I keep getting a NotSerializableException while attepting to serialize or deserialize its objects.

It should be noted that the attributes of this class are either int or String.

I just don't get why this exception is being thrown.

OK I can serialize it now but while deserializing only the first object is deserialized.
How to deserialize a number of objects of the same Class in the same file.

Comment: Do you want to, say, show us the exception trace?

Comment: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: v1.Vehicule
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at v1.LittleTest.main(LittleTest.java:43)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: v1.Vehicule
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at v1.Serveur.saveVehicule(Serveur.java:97)
 at v1.LittleTest.main(LittleTest.java:36)

Comment: So it's the class and not its contents that are the problem. What's it extending? Not a non-serialisable class without a no-args constructor? (Not sure what the readObject is about if you can't get it to serialise in the first place.)

Comment: The class isn't extending anything else. I just checked & it serializes. It is the deserialization which is the problem.

Comment: Is it perhaps the fact that I have serialized more than 1 object (of the same type) into the same file.

Comment: OK, now it works but only after commenting the catch block. Else it prints both the trace & the result. However it deserializes only the first object & leaves the others.

Comment: I assume all your non-transient, non-static fields are also Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a default no-arg constructor.

Comment: Completely unnecessary. The most derived non-`Serializable` class needs a no-args constructor accessible to the least derived `Serializable` class, but no others do.

Comment: It's not so much that a serializable class needs a default constructor, but that its first non-serializable superclass does.

Answer (score 0):

Just increment serializationVersionUId and use the new class whereever you need and test it. It should work.

Answer (score -2):

> How to deserialize a number of objects of the same Class in the same
>   file.

In a loop. Or else just call `readObject()` a second time on another line of code.